# How do I manually install an old cygwin package?

Tags: windows, cygwin, openldap

A project I am working on requires an old version of SLAPD (the LDAP 
server) and must run on Windows, hence I am using cygwin packages:

I've found a binary package of slapd version I need 2.2.x here:

http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/sourceware.org/pub/cygwin/release/...

How do I manually install it in cygwin? It does not seem to be a package-manager file format (like an RPM or a Deb), but is there a tool to install it for me?

FYI, I'm operating behind a corporate firewall that prevents me from viewing the main cygwin site (including the documentation), so please nobody tell me to RTFM - I wish I could!

Thanks

Comment: this is more tech support than programming related

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using the cygwin package installer to install this package, usually if you select to view the full info and scroll to the package you need you will see some info about the version.

Now if you click on the version number you will see that it changes from the oldest in the repository to the current. If your repository has the version you need then just finish the wizard.

Comment: It only cycles between the previous version and the newest version. No way to select a prior version older than the previous.

Answer (score 12):

If you need an older version, [the Cygwin time machine](http://www.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org/Cygwin/timemachine.html) might help.  To use it, I had to invoke setup.exe from the command line, giving it the `--no-verify`/`-X` option and it still wouldn't let me downgrade the "cygwin" package itself but at least it is, albeit very slowly, allowing me to install the version I wanted to test as a parallel installation.

Comment: Even if i use a fruitbat.org mirror the default selection uses the most recent versions. I have to double click on every single package to force installation of older version. Is there any possibility to avoid this pain?

Answer (score 1):

Some cygwin mirrors keep old package files, for example, http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/cygwin/
You can use Sonatype nexus to mirror an existing cygwin repository, but provide your own setup.ini .[image: nexus cygwin mirror config]

Copy the already downloaded repo content to c:\progs\nexus\sonatype-work\nexus\storage\mirror.isoc.org.il-pub-cygwin\
Put your own setup.ini and setup.bz2 there.
Start setup.exe with --no-verify
Paste

```
http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/mirror.isoc.org.il-pub-cygwin/
```

into the mirror selection box and click "Add"