# CLion does not recognize Cygwin compilers

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, cygwin, clion

I have recently install CLion on Windows 10 Professional, and I need to get Cygwin 2.5.2 to work with it. I have done all the steps listed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33707526/3016335), but nothing seems to be working. I have installed Cygwin with `gcc`, `g++` and `make`, and referenced that in CLion.

Below is my Cygwin `\bin\` folder, with the compilers selected.

[image: Cygwin Compilers]

I am also aware that you need to add `Cygwin path\bin` to the environment variable, `PATH`, which I have done:

[image: Path environment variable]

However CLion still fails to recognize anything in the `bin` folder:

[image: CLion cannot see compilers]

**Why could this be?**

Comment: can you run gcc/g++ from windows command line? try `gcc --version` for instance.

Comment: any error message or log output ?

Comment: When I try to run `gcc` with any arguments it runs fine.

Comment: Try to use CMake from Cygwin, not the bundled one. Looks like bundled CMake can't find your Cygwin installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and it was because make was missing even though I'd installed gcc-core and gcc-g++ as the docs say.

If make isn't installed it won't detect the C Compiler or C++ compiler as per your screenshot above, event though they are installed.