# I can't compile any project

Tags: mingw, clion

I have a problem with MinGW and CLion. I did every steps Rajat mentioned on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267305/how-to-setup-clion-for-compile-and-run/), and I configured MinGW for CLion :

Mingw installed for CLion
[image: Mingw installed for CLion]

I also added mingw to my environment path.

But when I click on Run >> Edit Configurations, I can't select any target, configuration, and I have to browse my .cpp for "Executable".

Configurations edition
[image: Configurations edition]

On the left, on my project name, there's a red cross, so it seems to be a problem somewhere, but I couldn't find it...

I have Windows 10, I installed CLion on my F:\ drive, and MinGW on my C:\ one. I also installed other JetBrains IDEs, and I don't have any problem with them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The message at the bottom of your 2nd screenshot says:

```
Error: Configuration is not specified
```

Set configuration to some value in "Configuration" combobox.

Comment: Thank you to replied. Actually, there isn't any available value in "Configuration" combobox...
http://i.imgur.com/X7KgRWN.png

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an installation problem.  My experience has been that CLion only fills in my *Run/Debug Configurations* after it has performed a successful CMake initialization.  In other words, until my `CMakeLists.txt` file is successfully processed, CLion does not provide any usable Run or Build configurations, only ones marked with red crosses as you describe.

Examine your `CMakeLists.txt` file for errors of omission or sequence and run *Tools->CMake->Reset Cache and Reload Project* and look for errors.  This [useful tutorial on CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/) may help.

You say that you don't have this problem with other JetBrains products.  That is because CLion has a dependency on CMake that the other JetBrains products don't have.