# can't run any program in clion

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, clion

I downloaded clion and went through the setup up guide provided by jetbeans at : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2016.3/quick-tutorial-on-configuring-clion-on-windows.html 
I tried setting up both cygwin and minGW as the environment but the program wouldn't run. I followed this question : [How to setup Clion for compile and RUN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267305/how-to-setup-clion-for-compile-and-run)

I have appended the directories of cygwin and minGW in path too but still i can't run my program.

It raises a long error which is :

```
CMake Error at /cygdrive/c/Users/dell/.CLion2016.3/system/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.6.3/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "/cygdrive/c/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe" is not able to compile a
  simple test program.
```

It fails with the following output:

```
   Change Dir: /cygdrive/c/Users/dell/Desktop/jetBeans/c_c++/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make.exe" "cmTC_2284f/fast"

  /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_2284f.dir/build.make
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_2284f.dir/build

  make[1]: Entering directory
  '/cygdrive/c/Users/dell/Desktop/jetBeans/c_c++/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


  Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_2284f.dir/testCCompiler.c.o

  /cygdrive/c/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -o
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_2284f.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c
  /cygdrive/c/Users/dell/Desktop/jetBeans/c_c++/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c


  gcc.exe: error:
  /cygdrive/c/Users/dell/Desktop/jetBeans/c_c++/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c:
  No such file or directory

  gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files

  compilation terminated.

  make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_2284f.dir/build.make:66:
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_2284f.dir/testCCompiler.c.o] Error 1

  make[1]: Leaving directory
  '/cygdrive/c/Users/dell/Desktop/jetBeans/c_c++/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


  make: *** [Makefile:126: cmTC_2284f/fast] Error 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/cygdrive/c/Users/dell/Desktop/jetBeans/c_c++/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/cygdrive/c/Users/dell/Desktop/jetBeans/c_c++/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

[Previous CMake output restored: 11-02-2017 04:45]
```

Comment: Please see [ask]. A Q&A site works best, when askers do ask questions. In case you missed it, you never even asked a question.

Comment: @IInspectable sorry, i just want the clion to run a program. please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced some issues when downloading the CLion product, because it didn't work for me a lot of times. However, I then found this video:

[Install & Configure CLion Student Copy|| best IDE for C/C++](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=K1AvSrfjpks).

What I did was that I uninstalled CLion MinGW, and I started from scratch again. It probably was not the best choice, but I could not pinpoint the problem at hand, so I then re-installed it by following the above video. CLion works for me now. The video is for installing CLion on a windows operating computer.

Just a recommendation, you can first look at the video to see if you made any mistake. Compare how the instructor in the video does it to how you did it. If you missed anything like importing a certain package (this video uses MinGW), then that's where you went wrong. That could also solve the issue then. If you cannot pinpoint the error, then try re-installing it. Good luck!

---

EDIT: why do you have MinGW and cygwin installed? You only need one of them.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. Few packages were not installed which i did after watching the video and it worked. I had minGW installed but it kept raising those errors so I installed cygwin to see if that works.

Comment: You saved my life with your advice to re-install the software