# Clion error: executable is not specified

Tags: cmake, cygwin, windows-10, executable, clion

I have recently installed Clion student version and I get the error executable not found whenever I try to run my code.
I installed cygwin with it as specified on their website and also, respective packages as required. Here's how my tool chains window looks[image: Cygwin is installed and works properly]

Here is my cmakelists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(coding)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES library.cpp library.h)
add_library(coding ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Here is the error that I get:
[image: Executable not specified]

I do not see any options in the executables list.I am using Windows 10.

What do I do?

Comment: Your CMake project builds only a library, which cannot be run by definition. So, what do you want from CLion to do on "Run"?

Comment: I am just trying to run the hello world program. All those files were auto generated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267305/how-to-setup-clion-for-compile-and-run).

> SHORT ANSWER (should be similar for MinGW too but I haven't tried it):
>
> 1. Install Cygwin with GCC, G++, GDB and CMake (the required versions)
> 2. Add full path to Cygwin 'bin' directory to Windows Environment variables
> 3. Restart CLion and check 'Settings' -> 'Build, Execution, Deployment' to make sure CLion has picked up the right versions of
>      Cygwin, make and gdb
> 4. Check the project configuration ('Run' -> 'Edit configuration') to make sure your project name appears there and you can select options
>      in 'Target', 'Configuration' and 'Executable' fields.
> 5. Build and then Run
> 6. Enjoy

EDIT:

Looking more closely at the screenshot, it looks like you are actually making a C++ library in which case you wouldn't have an executable and it can not be run - a library is compiled and then used in another application.

Comment: Step 4 is the problem. I don't see any options in the executable field

Comment: @krishna I think I answered your question better in my edit, this was also pointed out by Tsyvarez on your question

Comment: But I am not trying to make a library. I am trying to run the hello world program.

Comment: @krishna When you create a new project in CLion you should be able to select C++ Executable instead of C++ Library then

Answer (score 0):

***Note: As this is a very basic question which may confuse beginners coding in CLion IDE, I'm putting this thorough answer here to stay as a step by step guide.***

It seems you've selected **C++ Executable** when first creating the project. As CLion heavily depends on CMake (& thus `CMakeLists.txt`), you can change the project type from a **C++ Library** to **C++ Executable**. To do this, replace the following line:

```
add_library(coding ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

with:

```
add_executable(coding ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Afterwards, select the desired file to execute from the "Executable" combo-box in "Edit Configuration" dialogue.

Now you're done. But if you wanna make your project clean, you may follow these steps to make it a pure executable project (rather being a library one):

1. remove the `library.h` from `set(SOURCE_FILES library.cpp library.h)` in `CMakeLists.txt` file.
2. remove the `#include "library.h"` from the beginning of `library.cpp` file.

Now your project seems like it was first created as a C++ Executable project.